# Connecting between international flights at Miami (MIA) and Fort Lauderdale (FLL)

Tags: transit, airport-transfer, fll, mia, guyana

I have one query  - I am Indian national and have valid USA visa B1/B2, and my flight from Georgetown (GEO) to Miami (MIA) is on BW-484 and connecting flight after 8.5hrs will be from Fort Lauderdale (FLL) is on EK-214 and EK-512 for New Delhi (DEL).

Will there be any problem if I change the airport or should I take my connecting flight from Miami (MIA) itself?

Please suggest and share some experience of the consequences.

Comment: You have 8.5 hours to retrieve your baggage, drive across town and check-in to your connecting flight. I can't see that there'd be a problem. On the other hand, if you can change flights at MIA, let the airline interline your baggage, and enjoy a relaxed meal in a restaurant instead of worrying about the traffic, why wouldn't you?

Comment: I had probably the worst experience of my life trying to locate the vehicle rental return depot at Miami. Unless you’re familiar with the airport layout and connections to FL, I wouldn’t risk it. 8.5 hours seems like a long time but there are lots of risk factors outside your control - late inbound flight, traffic etc. - that could cause a problem, or at the very least be unnecessarily stressful. InsanityRules is right - why complicate the trip instead of relaxing.

Comment: What time of day and day of the week would your connection be?  The amount of time required to drive from MIA to FLL can vary significantly depending on when you travel and the level of traffic present.

Answer (score 4):

It would certainly be easier and more comfortable if you were to connect directly in Miami, but an 8.5 hours connection is entirely doable.

Transport options

1. Take the train (http://www.tri-rail.com/airport-connections/). Cost is very low (<5$) but the train schedule is only about once an hour and there are extra shuttle bus rides from the train stations to the actual terminals. I think they are free, but can be hassle, especially of you have lots of luggage
2. Shared Van (https://booking.supershuttle.com/?RezMode=1&direction=RT&_ga=2.154460798.772710600.1526132486-268259906.1526132486 for example). You book in advance and they'll drive you from airport to airport. There may be other passengers and other stops, so it'll typically take longer than a direct connection. Price would start around $45 or so.
3. Better van: same as #2) but you can pay more money for a direct connection and/or have a car to yourself. Around $100.
4. Rental car. Around $60 + insurance. This still requires using the people mover in MIA and a shuttle in FLL, so it's similar to the train. It takes some time to pick and drop off the car. Driving down there during rush hour is NO fun, so I would only consider this only if you are comfortable with heavy urban traffic in the US.
5. Uber/Lyft. $40-$50 unless it's high demand or you have a lot of luggage or people. Very easy, you request when you have your luggage, meet at the pick up point and the driver will drop you off right at your the terminal at FLL. https://www.uber.com/airports/mia/
6. Taxi. Maybe $100? Hard to tell upfront.

Personally, I would do Uber, especially if you are more than one person in your party. Only exception terrible traffic conditions, in which case I would use the train. The good thing about this approach is that you can decide when you get there. Once landed you can check traffic and Uber price & availability. If it's good, get an Uber, if it's horrible head to the train station.